# Linq query to get data from DB says null even if there is data available

Tags: c#, database, linq

Query is linq in c# and it compares the start and stop date which I input, which is always of 15 min interval.

And this start and stop is compared with database startDB and stopDB. Even though there is data available in the database, nothing gets returned.

- Input: my_startTime: 11.15 am  & my_stopTime: 11.30 am
- Compared to database: startTime: 10:00 am & stopTime: 12:00pm

My query is

```
var data = DbUpdateLoop.context.EnergyPeakInfo_Tbl
                  .Where(x => (my_startTime >= x.StartTime) && (my_stopTime <= x.StopTime))
                  .FirstOrDefault();

if (data == null)
{
    MsgBox = "No data available in DB";
}
```

Here, `DbUpdateLoop.context` is my `DbContext` and `EnergyPeakInfo_Tbl` is my table name where my database has the following data:

```
 EID     datetime.now        type  startTime            EndTime
    1   8/23/2016 11:06 AM  2   OFF 8/23/2016 10:45 AM  8/23/2016 11:15 AM  0   
    2   8/23/2016 11:06 AM  0   ON  8/23/2016 11:15 AM  8/23/2016 12:00 PM  0
```

It sometime gets the data but sometimes says null... what is the reason?
i tried giving it my_startTime.date and my_stopTime.date but did not work

Comment: Maybe the db-datetimes have  milliseconds  but your input-time not

Comment: Also make sure the timezones are correct. See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39439), maybe it helps

Comment: @TimSchmelter how do i trim and improve on this?

Comment: @AndrasToth time zone on both side is the same, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the query and the following should work as you expected:

```
 var result = TimeTables
   .Where (
      c => 
            (((c.StartTime >= (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse("14:20:00"))) && 
                  (c.StopTime <= (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse("15:30:00")))
               ) || 
                  ((c.StopTime <= (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse("15:30:00"))) && 
                     (c.StopTime >= (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse("14:20:00")))
                  )
              )
          )
```

Or more specifically for time: Extracted only time from DateTime - c.StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay

```
 TimeTables
   .Where (
      c => 
            (((c.StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay >= (TimeSpan.Parse("14:20:00"))) && 
                  (c.StopTime.Value.TimeOfDay <= (TimeSpan.Parse("15:30:00")))
               ) || 
                  ((c.StopTime.Value.TimeOfDay <= (TimeSpan.Parse("15:30:00"))) && 
                     (c.StopTime.Value.TimeOfDay >= (TimeSpan.Parse("14:20:00")))
                  )
              )
          )
```

Remember you have to convert the 12 hour time format into 24 as input.
By the way, the table structure I used as follows:

```
Table - TimeTables:
ID - StartTime - StopTime
 1 - 2016-08-23 13:00:00.000 - 2016-08-23 14:00:00.000
 2 - 2016-08-23 14:00:00.000 - 2016-08-23 15:00:00.000
```

Comment: may i know what is start and end in your query. @AT-2016

Comment: That's actually variable names that I used. Change it according to yours.